# Interne Serverfout after one click update

Tags: updating

Hello and good evening,

After the one click update the message 'Interne Serverfout' appears on the screen. One can no longer connect to either the fron or backend of the installation ?

What is the correct procedure to roll back to a working website here ?

-Ruud

Comment: Per .htacces file the server is configured using: php_value memory_limit 225M php_value max_execution_time 50 Which are the maximum values allowed by the web host. After restoring the .sql backup and setting craftcms/cms version requirement to the previous version. The systems prompts me that changes need to be made to the database -> The spinner starts -> The all done message appears, the page then reloads with the error message Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

Interne Serverfout (Internal Server Error) is a fatal error that has happened and your web server killed the request.

Usually, fatal errors like this are either because PHP times out, or runs out of memory... the underlying error message will be either in your web server's error logs or Craft error logs.

Try editing your php.ini file and increasing the `memory_limit` setting to at least 256M, and the `max_execution_time` setting to at least 120.

If you’re not sure where your php.ini file is located, create a PHP file called `ini.php` alongside your `index.php` file with this:

```
php
echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . php_ini_loaded_file();
```

Then access that file in your web browser by going to `http://your-project.test/ini.php`.

Once you’ve made your changes, restart your web server, restore your database from a pre-update attempt database backup and then try again.